# prevent first input focus in ionic

Tags: css, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have a login screen to application and when launching,the 'username' input gets the focus automatically and pops out the keyboard. when the keyboard pops out contents of my login screen pushes up resulting in wrong dimensions.

How can i prevent this auto focusing of the first input ?

And also a point to note is this only happens in iOS. In android it works just fine.

This is how it is displayed when the application is launched(Blocking the fields and pushing the contents up)
[image]

Here's my code

```
<ion-view title="*************" hide-back-button="false" >

  <ion-content class="has-header" scroll="false" >




  <center style="position:relative;">

<div id="logo">
           <img src="img/lof_logo.png" style="margin-top:40px;" class="img-responsive" width="270"/>
        </div>




  <div  class="box on fadein fadeout " ng-show="toggle" ng-animate="'box'"  style="z-index:1"  >


      <div  class="container" ng-controller="LoginController">

      <form id="ftForm" name="form" autocomplete="off" novalidate shake-that  ng-submit="login(credentials)" novalidate>


          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group box-shadow" ng-class="{'has-error': form.name.$invalid && submitted}">

             <input style="padding-left:5px;"
                 type="text"
                 class="form-control"
                 id="username"
                 name="username"
                 placeholder="User Name"
                 ng-model="credentials.username"
                 ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'blur'}"
                 required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group box-shadow" ng-class="{'has-error': form.password.$invalid && submitted}">

              <input style="padding-left:5px;"
                type="password"
                class="form-control"
                id="password"
                name="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                ng-model="credentials.password"
                required>
            </div>


          </div>

<div class="box-shadow" >


 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" >Login</button>

</div>
      </form>

      <div class="alert alert-success message" ng-show="showMessage">Well done!</div>

    </div>


  </div>

<a href="#"> 

    <img src="img/online_banking_bg.png" class="img-responsive" style="margin-top:40px; z-index: 1; margin-bottom:40px; " ng-click="toggle = !toggle" />

 </a> 
<ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" style="height:250px;">




    <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="col">

               <a style="font-size: 20px; color:" href="#/app/services/product">
                  <i class="icon ion-arrow-graph-up-right" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                           <h5>Products and Services</h5>

                </a>

          </div>
          <div class="col">

             <a style="font-size: 20px; color:" href="#/app/services/locations">
                  <i class="icon ion-android-location" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                           <h5>Locate a Branch / ATM</h5>

            </a>
          </div>

    </div>
     <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="col">

               <a style="font-size: 20px; color:" href="#/app/services/calc">
                  <i class="icon ion-ios7-calculator" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                           <h5>Financial Calculator</h5>

                </a>

          </div>
          <div class="col">

             <a style="font-size: 20px; color:" href="#/app/services/news">
                  <i class="icon ion-ios7-world-outline" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                           <h5>News and CSR</h5>

            </a>
          </div>

    </div>
     <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
          <div class="col">

               <a style="font-size: 20px; color:" href="#/app/services/promotion">
                  <i class="icon ion-android-promotion" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                           <h5>Promotions and Offers</h5>

                </a>

          </div>
          <div class="col">

             <a style="font-size: 20px; color:" href="#/app/services/contact">
                  <i class="icon ion-ios7-telephone" style="font-size: 50px;"></i>
                           <h5>Contact and Feedback</h5>

            </a>
          </div>

    </div>

     <br/><br/>

 </ion-scroll>

 <!-- 

    <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                  <div class="button-bar">
                      <a class="button" href="#/app/services/product">Small</a>
                      <a class="button" href="#/app/account/balance">Medium</a>
                      <a class="button" ng-click="showImage(3)">Very large</a>
                  </div>
    </div>

-->
</center>
<script id="image-modal.html" type="text/ng-template">
              <div class="modal image-modal transparent">
                  <ion-pane class="transparent">
                     <img ng-src="{{imageSrc}}" class="fullscreen-image"/>
                  </ion-pane>
              </div>
    </script>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tabindex` attribute to direct the focus. Setting it to `-1` will never auto focus.

Comment: where can i find the tabindex attribute?

Comment: It's a [html attribute](http://www.w3.org/WAI/UA/TS/html401/cp0101/0101-TABINDEX.html). You can place it any element that can receive focus.

Comment: i set it to -1 but the still i found that issue

Comment: Hmmm ... I don't have an iOS device with me to check this, but what happens if you give one of your `<a>` elements a tabindex with the value `"0"` or `"1"`?

Answer (score 2):

[Inspired by Github: xclusive36 commented on Nov 27, 2020](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/21982#issuecomment-734999212)

To force ion-input to not steal focus,
Set ion-button/ion-input with attribute tabIndex="-1",

```
<ion-item> <ion-input tabindex="-1">foo</ion-input> <ion-button tabindex="-1" >foo</ion-button></ion-item>
```

As a side effect, the ion-button will take on a border when focused.
Add to css to remove the border.

```
ion-input:focus{ outline: none; }
ion-button:focus{ outline: none; }
```